# Custom datasource plugin on EMR throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scalaj/http/Http

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm using a custom data source located here https://github.com/sourav-mazumder/Data-Science-Extensions/releases

When I work with this locally using a Dockerized Spark environment it works as expected. However when I use it on EMR I get the error in this questions title. Following are the EMR configuration options used, the Spark startup messages and the test code and result when I run it. I'm not sure what else I need to configure.

[image: aws emr console configuration]

The configuration is:

```
[
  {
    "configurations": [
      {
        "classification": "export",
        "properties": {
          "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
        }
      }
    ],
    "classification": "spark-env",
    "properties": {}
  },
  {
    "configurations": [
      {
        "classification": "export",
        "properties": {
          "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
        }
      }
    ],
    "classification": "yarn-env",
    "properties": {}
  },
  {
    "classification": "spark-defaults",
    "properties": {
      "spark.executor.extraClassPath": "/home/hadoop/*",
      "spark.driver.extraClassPath": "/home/hadoop/*",
      "spark.jars.packages": "org.scalaj:scalaj-http_2.10:2.3.0"
    }
  }
]
```

There's also a boot strap step to copy the datasource JAR available at the link above, which I uploaded to S3, to each node in the spark cluster at `/home/hadoop`:

```
aws s3 cp s3://foo/spark-datasource-rest_2.11-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/hadoop/spark-datasource-rest_2.11-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

When I SSH into the master node and start a PySpark session (as `ec2-user`) I see the following messages:

```
sudo pyspark 
Python 3.6.7 (default, Dec 21 2018, 20:31:01) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/ec2-user/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/ec2-user/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/lib/spark/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
org.scalaj#scalaj-http_2.10 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-200abadc-d4a6-47dd-a2e9-110f77de3b4e;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found org.scalaj#scalaj-http_2.10;2.3.0 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 140ms :: artifacts dl 5ms
    :: modules in use:
    org.scalaj#scalaj-http_2.10;2.3.0 from central in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   1   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-200abadc-d4a6-47dd-a2e9-110f77de3b4e
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 1 already retrieved (0kB/6ms)
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
19/04/11 19:00:35 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
19/04/11 19:00:36 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
19/04/11 19:00:40 WARN Client: Same path resource file:///home/ec2-user/.ivy2/jars/org.scalaj_scalaj-http_2.10-2.3.0.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.0
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.7 (default, Dec 21 2018 20:31:01)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

Then I run my test code:

```
sodauri = 'https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/6yvf-kk3n.json'
sodainput1 = [("Nevada"), ("nn")]
sodainput2 = [("Northern California"), ("pr")]
sodainput3 = [("Virgin Islands region"), ("pr")]
sodainputRdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([sodainput1, sodainput2, sodainput3])
sodaDf = sodainputRdd.toDF(["region","source"])
sodaDf.createOrReplaceTempView('sodainputtbl')                         
prmsSoda = { 'url' : sodauri, 'input' : 'sodainputtbl', 'method' : 'GET', 'readTimeout' : '10000', 'connectionTimeout' : '2000', 'partitions' : '10'}
sodasDf = spark.read.format("org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestDataSource").options(**prmsSoda).load()
[Stage 6:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]19/04/11 20:34:39 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 8, ip-10-100-14-225.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 3): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scalaj/http/Http$
    at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestConnectorUtil$.callRestAPI(RestConnectorUtil.scala:53)
    at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RESTRelation.org$apache$dsext$spark$datasource$rest$RESTRelation$$callRest(RestRelation.scala:128)
    at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RESTRelation$$anonfun$2.apply(RestRelation.scala:100)
    at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RESTRelation$$anonfun$2.apply(RestRelation.scala:100)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:331)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceLeftOption(TraversableOnce.scala:203)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeftOption(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceOption(TraversableOnce.scala:210)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceOption(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scalaj.http.Http$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 31 more

19/04/11 20:34:39 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o193.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 6.0 (TID 11, ip-10-100-14-225.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 3): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scalaj/http/Http$
    at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestConnectorUtil$.callRestAPI(RestConnectorUtil.scala:53)
    at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RESTRelation.org$apache$dsext$spark$datasource$rest$RESTRelation$$callRest(RestRelation.scala:128)
    at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RESTRelation$$anonfun$2.apply(RestRelation.scala:100)
    at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RESTRelation$$anonfun$2.apply(RestRelation.scala:100)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:331)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceLeftOption(TraversableOnce.scala:203)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeftOption(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceOption(TraversableOnce.scala:210)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceOption(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2039)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2027)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2026)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2026)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2260)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2209)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2198)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:777)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$.infer(JsonInferSchema.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.TextInputJsonDataSource$$anonfun$inferFromDataset$1.apply(JsonDataSource.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.TextInputJsonDataSource$$anonfun$inferFromDataset$1.apply(JsonDataSource.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.TextInputJsonDataSource$.inferFromDataset(JsonDataSource.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader$$anonfun$2.apply(DataFrameReader.scala:439)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader$$anonfun$2.apply(DataFrameReader.scala:439)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:419)
    at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RESTRelation.<init>(RestRelation.scala:101)
    at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestDataSource.createRelation(RestDataSource.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scalaj/http/Http$
    at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestConnectorUtil$.callRestAPI(RestConnectorUtil.scala:53)
    at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RESTRelation.org$apache$dsext$spark$datasource$rest$RESTRelation$$callRest(RestRelation.scala:128)
    at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RESTRelation$$anonfun$2.apply(RestRelation.scala:100)
    at org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RESTRelation$$anonfun$2.apply(RestRelation.scala:100)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:331)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceLeftOption(TraversableOnce.scala:203)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeftOption(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceOption(TraversableOnce.scala:210)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceOption(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema$$anonfun$1.apply(JsonInferSchema.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
>>>
```

What's wrong with my configuration?

#### Update

I've tried configuring the EMR cluster with `scalaj-http_2.11` but I still get the same error. I also rebuilt the plugin making sure it was built for version 2.11.12 of Scala and Spark 2.4, the same as those running on EMR. I'm still getting the same error.

I'm looking into the warning messages now in case that's the problem:

```
Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.

Same path resource file:///home/ec2-user/.ivy2/jars/org.scalaj_scalaj-http_2.10-2.3.0.jar added multiple times to distributed cache.
```

Comment: I would guess it's the incompatible scala version that creates the issue, you should have better results with `org.scalaj:scalaj-http_2.11:2.3.0`

Comment: @rluta, thanks for the response. I have already tried doing this, recreating the entire EMR cluster with the configuration specifying 2.11 instead. When Spark starts it reports that it found the 2.11 library (in the same way the above seems to find the 2.10 one). Even so, I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working

Seems it's something to do with the packages configuration not working. Instead I copied the required `scalaj-http_2.11:2.3.0` jar from the maven downloads repo to the same directory that the custom datasource plugin was also copied to. Now it's working (with the `spark.jars.packages` line removed from the EMR configuration)